# Character not collecting animated coins

Tags: unity, character, scene

I am trying to make a simple game where the player jumps and collects animated coins. After collecting all the coins, the scene is supposed to change. For some reason, my character collects the coins but the scene doesn't change.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Coins : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string newLevel;
    public int coinAmount;
    int coins ;



        void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
        {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            coins += 1;

            Destroy(gameObject);
            addCoins();

        }
    }


    void addCoins()
    {
        coins++;

        if (coins == coinAmount)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(newLevel);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the game: [image]

Comment: Did you mean to nest your OnTriggerEnter2D function inside your Start function like that?

Comment: @DMGregory No I did not, don't know how I let that slip. I have tried to fix the code now but it still isn't working.

Comment: Did you mean to spell OnTriggerEnter2D with an uppercase D as in the documentation?

Comment: @DMGregory Yes I don't know why I am making such silly mistakes . So now the coins get destroyed but the next scene still doesn't load after all the coins have been destroyed, for some reason

Comment: can you share screen shot of then game play. so we could understand what sort of game it is, is it 2d or 3d. which type of collider is coin and player using. As 2d collider does not work with 3d collider.
Also ther is uper Case D for OnTriggerEnter2D.

Comment: @Swati Okay I will update my question with a screenshot. It is a 2d game and yes, I made the silly mistake of using 2d instead of 2D

Comment: Which type of collide are you using on player and coin. Also is there rigid body 2D attached to the player or coins?

Comment: Ok, you got coin issue fixed which is greet. about the scene i believe its because you have not added the scene (which you want to load or Target scene) is not added to "Scenes in Build". I have answered this question here:  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709664/why-doesnt-my-scene-finish-loading-unity/58711031#58711031

Comment: @Swati there is a rigid body attached to the player. Thank you, I will take a look at that link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100773/discussion-between-user19964-and-swati).

Comment: Is your target coin amount an odd number perchance? You're always adding two coins at a time, so you might be jumping from leas than your target to more that your target, without hitting it exactly.

Comment: @DMGregory yes, it is 5 coins. How would I change the code to account for that? Also I have other scenes with an even number, is does the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your `OnTriggerEnter2D` function in this script, it looks like this is the script you're placing on each individual coin.

That means that each individual coin has its own copy of the `coins` variable.

So you're not accumulating a total of how many coins are collected in your whole scene, you're just counting how many times *this* coin was collected.

To fix this, you can make the variable `static`, which makes it shared between all instances of the script. That might looks something like this:

```
public class Coin : MonoBehaviour {

    static int _coinsLeftToCollect = 0;

    [SerializeField]
    string _nextScene;

    // Keep a count of how many coins are still active in this scene.
    // Doing this in OnEnable/OnDisable ensures each scene starts from zero.
    void OnEnable() {
        _coinsLeftToCollect++;
    }

    // When the count hits zero, trigger the load.
    void OnDisable() {
        // You may want to add an additional condition to skip triggering
        // the next scene, if you're already unloading this scene for another reason.
        if(--_coinsLeftToCollect == 0) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(_nextScene);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D() {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            // This will call OnDisable as the script is destroyed.
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer makes sense. It works well :) @DMGregory